# my useEffect is reaching callstack and after text change, i don't know why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i want to fire a callback after a text change, basically this is for search. My code:

```
const fetchMovies = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log('fetchMovies api ');
    const {Search} = await fetch(
      `http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${apiKey}&s=${text}&page=${page}`,
    ).then(data => data.json());
    console.log('movies', Search);
    return Search;
  }, [page, text]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect!');
    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    if (text) {
      const newTimeout = setTimeout(async () => {
        dispatch(fetchMoviesRequest('fetch'));
        console.log('fetch!1');
        try {
          const moviesResult = await fetchMovies();
          console.log('fetch!2', moviesResult);
          dispatch(fetchMoviesSuccess(moviesResult));
        } catch (fetchError) {
          console.log('fetch!3e', fetchError);
          dispatch(fetchMoviesFailure(fetchError));
        }
      }, 2000);
      dispatch(onSetTimeout(newTimeout));
    }
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [fetchMovies, text, timeout, page]);
```

somehow i cannot figure out what causes it to rerender so much when it's supposed to rerender only after text change? i can only type 1 letter and app crashes with error of max call stack?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the values of your other variables are in your useEffect dependency array, but what looks suspicious to me is that you have `timeout` as one of the dependencies.

I'm going on a hunch and say that this line `onSetTimeout(newTimeout)` will change the value of the `timeout` variable which will re-trigger this useEffect. This will create an infinite loop because the effect will run every time `timeout` changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your `useEffect`'s dependency list to only `[text]`?

I'm not too sure, but I think that'll only call the function if `text` changes.